# Cross records between tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
select pa.id,pa.name 
from patients pa 
where (select count(distinct co.doctorID) 
       from consults co 
       where co.patientID=pa.id) = (select count(do.id) 
                                    from doctors do);
```

In which I select the patients who had consults with all the doctors.

I am counting the number of distinct doctors and see if is equal to the total of doctors.

But how can I do this with an `exists` and/or `in` without using count

Comment: Please, specify the DBMS in your question or with a tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select pa.id,pa.name 
from patients pa 
where NOT EXISTS
(
   select 1 FROM doctors do
   where NOT EXISTS
   (
      SELECT 1 FROM consults co
      WHERE co.doctorID=do.id
      AND pa.id=co.patientID
   )
)
```

In other words, select all patients without a doctor that was not consulted. At least it should give you the idea.

Comment: Works perfectly and i understood the idea!
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try even better solution with `NOT EXISTS` that will not require counts at all:

```
SELCT pa.id,pa.name 
FROM patients pa 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *  
                  FROM doctors do 
                       LEFT JOIN consults co  
                             ON co.doctorID ON do.id
                  WHERE co.patientID=pa.id 
                      AND co.doctorID IS NULL

    )
```

In sub-query we get all the doctors and see whether all of them have consult for current patient. If co.doctorID IS NULL, that doctor was not visited by patient.